# Having trouble figure out why my doubly linked list is falling apart and I could use some direction

Tags: c++, linked-list

**Full disclosure**: This is a project for my class, but I'm not here to ask you to do my homework for me. I'm looking for a little direction as to what I seem to be missing.

**The assignment**: From a file of formatted data (see below). You are to create 3 doubly linked lists. (so one set of data with three "chains" that orders the data numerically) If you come across an piece of data with the same timestamp as a previous piece of data, that data is considered to be unreliable and needs to be deleted from the doubly linked list.

**The Problem**: I have four linked list heads, timeHead, tempHead, and windHead are for the data being read in from the file. The last is duplHead (duplicateHead) is for a list of duplicates. My issue is that whenever I try to delete a particular node from my linked list. I cant seem to do it correctly. I either crash the program or the doubly linked list falls apart.

Here is my code: I feel my main problem is either not creating the list correctly OR not deleting the problem nodes correctly.

The int main function only calls two functions addData and print report. I have included what I felt was relevant.

```
//ADD TO LINKED LIST
void linkedlist::addToLinkedList(weatherdata *newNode){

int doubleMarker = 0;
weatherdata *newNodeCopy;
weatherdata *currentNode;
weatherdata *nextNode;

newNodeCopy = new weatherdata;      //  <-- NEW
newNodeCopy = newNode;

/*_____ lINKED lIST FOR TIMESTAMP _____*/

//checks the duplicate list so as not to add a deleted triple
if (isItInDuplicateList(newNode) == 1){
    doubleMarker = 1;
}

//if something exists in the list do this: traverse the list, check for duplicates.
if ((timeHead != nullptr) && (doubleMarker != 1)){  

    currentNode = timeHead;

    while (currentNode != nullptr){

        //if its the same as another item DELETE
        if (newNode->time == currentNode->time) {
            addToDuplicateList(newNode);
            deleteNodeFromList(newNode);
            doubleMarker = 1;   //      <-- this double marker will ensure that the function doesnt add a duplicate item
            break;
        }

        currentNode = currentNode->timeN;
    }       
}
//if the incoming number is not a duplicate of something we already have on our list we add it
if (doubleMarker != 1){
    //very first item on list
    if (timeHead == nullptr){
        timeHead = newNodeCopy;
    }
    //first position on list
    else if (newNode->time < timeHead->time){
        nextNode = timeHead;
        timeHead = newNodeCopy;
        newNodeCopy->timeN = nextNode;
        nextNode->timeP = newNodeCopy;
    }
    //either between 2 entries or at the end of the list
    else {
        //traverse the list and find the appropriate placement for the newNode
        currentNode = timeHead;
        nextNode = timeHead->timeN;

        //while "not yet at the end of the list"
        while (nextNode != nullptr){

            //newNode belongs somewhere in between two other entries
            if ((currentNode->time < newNode->time) && (newNode->time < nextNode->time)){
                currentNode->timeN = newNodeCopy;
                newNodeCopy->timeP = currentNode;
                newNodeCopy->timeN = nextNode;
                nextNode->timeP = newNodeCopy;
                break;
            }
            //otherwise increment currentNode and nextNode and compare again
            else {
                currentNode = nextNode;
                nextNode = nextNode->timeN;
            }
        }
        //newNode goes at the end of the linked List
        if (nextNode == nullptr){
            currentNode->timeN = newNodeCopy;
            newNodeCopy->timeP = currentNode;
        }
    }
}

/*_____ lINKED lIST FOR TEMPERATURE _____*/

//if the incoming number is not a duplicate of something we already have on our list we add it
if (doubleMarker != 1){
    //very first item on list
    if (tempHead == nullptr){
        tempHead = newNodeCopy;
    }
    //first position on list
    else if (newNode->temp < tempHead->temp){
        nextNode = tempHead;
        tempHead = newNodeCopy;
        newNodeCopy->tempN = nextNode;
        nextNode->tempP = newNodeCopy;
    }
    //either between 2 entries or at the end of the list
    else {
        //traverse the list and find the appropriate placement for the newNode
        currentNode = tempHead;
        nextNode = tempHead->tempN;

        //while "not yet at the end of the list"
        while (nextNode != nullptr){

            //newNode belongs somewhere in between two other entries
            if ((currentNode->temp <= newNode->temp) && (newNode->temp <= nextNode->temp)){
                currentNode->tempN = newNodeCopy;
                newNodeCopy->tempN = nextNode;
                nextNode->tempP = newNodeCopy;
                break;
            }
            //otherwise increment currentNode and nextNode and compare again
            else {
                currentNode = nextNode;
                nextNode = nextNode->tempN;
            }
        }
        //newNode goes at the end of the linked List
        if (nextNode == nullptr){
            currentNode->tempN = newNodeCopy;
            newNodeCopy->tempP = currentNode;
        }
    }
}

/*_____ lINKED lIST FOR WINDSPEED _____*/

//if the incoming number is not a duplicate of something we already have on our list we add it
if (doubleMarker != 1){
    //very first item on list
    if (windHead == nullptr){
        windHead = newNodeCopy;
    }
    //first position on list
    else if (newNode->wind < windHead->wind){
        nextNode = windHead;
        windHead = newNodeCopy;
        newNodeCopy->windN = nextNode;
        nextNode->windP = newNodeCopy;
    }
    //either between 2 entries or at the end of the list
    else {
        //traverse the list and find the appropriate placement for the newNode
        currentNode = windHead;
        nextNode = windHead->windN;

        //while "not yet at the end of the list"
        while (nextNode != nullptr){

            //newNode belongs somewhere in between two other entries
            if ((currentNode->wind <= newNode->wind) && (newNode->wind <= nextNode->wind)){
                currentNode->windN = newNodeCopy;
                newNodeCopy->windN = nextNode;
                nextNode->windP = newNodeCopy;
                break;
            }
            //otherwise increment currentNode and nextNode and compare again
            else {
                currentNode = nextNode;
                nextNode = nextNode->windN;
            }
        }
        //newNode goes at the end of the linked List
        if (nextNode == nullptr){
            currentNode->windN = newNodeCopy;
            newNodeCopy->windP = currentNode;
        }
    }
}
}

//ADD TO DUPLICATE LIST
void linkedlist::addToDuplicateList(weatherdata *duplicateNode){

weatherdata *currentNode;
weatherdata *nextNode;
weatherdata *addDuplicateNode;

addDuplicateNode = new weatherdata;     //      <-- NEW

//make a complete copy for the duplicate list (since were going to delete that node)
addDuplicateNode->time = duplicateNode->time;
addDuplicateNode->temp = duplicateNode->temp;
addDuplicateNode->wind = duplicateNode->wind;   
addDuplicateNode->timeN = duplicateNode->timeN;
addDuplicateNode->timeP = duplicateNode->timeP;
addDuplicateNode->tempN = duplicateNode->tempN;
addDuplicateNode->tempP = duplicateNode->tempP;
addDuplicateNode->windN = duplicateNode->windN;
addDuplicateNode->windP = duplicateNode->windP;
addDuplicateNode->duplN = duplicateNode->duplN;

if (duplHead == nullptr){
    duplHead = addDuplicateNode;
}
else {
    currentNode = duplHead;
    nextNode = duplHead->duplN;

    while (nextNode != nullptr){
        currentNode = nextNode;
        nextNode = nextNode->duplN;
    }   

    currentNode->duplN = addDuplicateNode;
}
}


/DELETE FROM LINKEDLIST
void linkedlist::deleteNodeFromList(weatherdata *toBeDeletedNode){

weatherdata *currentNode;
weatherdata *nextNode;

currentNode = timeHead;
nextNode = timeHead->timeN; 

while (nextNode != nullptr){

    if (nextNode->time == toBeDeletedNode->time){

        currentNode->timeN = nextNode->timeN;
        //currentNode->tempN = nextNode->tempN;
        //cout << ".";
        delete toBeDeletedNode;
        toBeDeletedNode = nullptr;
        break;
    }

    currentNode = nextNode;
    nextNode = nextNode->timeN;
}
}

//DUPLICATE LIST CHECK
bool linkedlist::isItInDuplicateList(weatherdata *checkThisNode){

bool found = false;

weatherdata *currentNode;   
currentNode = duplHead;

if (duplHead == nullptr){
    found = false;
}
else {

    do {

        if (currentNode->time == checkThisNode->time) {
            found = true;
            break;
        }
        currentNode = currentNode->duplN;
    } while (currentNode != nullptr);
}

return found;   
}
```

So either the first (long) function linkedlist addToLinkedList();
or the last (short) function linkedlist deleteNodeFromList();

If you need me to post anymore code please let me know and I'll so so.
Again, I feel like I'm either not making the doubly linked list correctly or not deleting it right.

Thanks again!

Comment: The right tool to solve such problems is your debugger. You should step through your code line-by-line *before* asking on Stack Overflow. For more help, please read [How to debug small programs (by Eric Lippert)](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). At a minimum, you should \[edit] your question to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example that reproduces your problem, along with the observations you made in the debugger.

Comment: You have a very long function and lots of duplicated codes. You should try split it into serval short functions (may be up to 40 lines) and try to avoid code duplication first. This will help you with debugging.

Answer (score 1):

First take a look at these lines:

```
 newNodeCopy = new weatherdata;      //  <-- NEW
 newNodeCopy = newNode;
```

In the first line you create a new object of type `weatherdata` and saves a pointer to the new object in `newNodeCopy`.

In the second line you overwrite the value of `newNodeCopy` with the value of `newNode` which means you have lost the pointer to the new object (i.e. you have a memory leak).

If you want to copy the values from the object that `newNode` points to into the newly created object, you need to do:

```
 *newNodeCopy = *newNode;
```

In general I'll recommend that you split the function into three smaller functions (i.e. one for each list). Smaller functions are easier to understand and debug.

Also I noticed this part:

```
if (isItInDuplicateList(newNode) == 1){
    doubleMarker = 1;
}
```

In all the remaining code in the function you do:

```
if (doubleMarker != 1){
    .....
}
```

In other words - once `doubleMarker` is set to `1`, you don't execute more code. Therefore you can simplify your code by returning right away. Like:

```
if (isItInDuplicateList(newNode) == 1){
    return;
}
```

Then you can remove all the `if (doubleMarker != 1){` and your code gets more simple to read, understand and debug.

**The delete function**

Your `void linkedlist::deleteNodeFromList(weatherdata *toBeDeletedNode)` have some serious problems - consider this:

1) What will happen if `timeHead` is nullptr ?

2) Where do you check if `timeHead->time == toBeDeletedNode->time` ?

3) Where do you update the `timeP` pointer ?

The answers are:

1) Program crash

2) Never - so you can't delete the head element.

3) Never - so your list is broken! You need to add code that updates the "previous" pointer

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to go over this, i really appreciate it. I'm gonna take a look and try to fix some of the things you suggested.